# gnu parallel single job splitted in multi-threads

Tags: bash, multithreading, process, nohup, gnu-parallel

I want to launch a single job, that takes in input two parameters, and split its execution between 128 thread of the CPU with GNUparallel. I explain what I did and how I did it, and ask for help.

I have a bash script "job.sh" where I define two variables and launch a job

```
#!/bin/bash

first=70
second=10

./executable $((first-1)) $second

echo "$first $second"
```

now I want to split this intense job in 128 threads of the CPU of the server I'm woring on, using GNU parallel.

After reading the documentation, I tried to substitute the row `./executable $((first-1)) $second` with `parallel -j+128 ./executable $((first-1)) $second`, the  I tried to run it as follows:

```
user@server$ nohup bash job.sh&
```

the job fails. Anyone knows how to run an executable with GNU parallel?

Comment: Do you want to start all jobs with the same arguments (`./executable 69 10`) or should the first argument (`69`) always be reduced by one to (`6`)?

Comment: the job is one; 69 and 10 are the input parameters for my single job; i just want to split the work around 64 threads.

Comment: You just want to run `./executable 69 10` 64 times in parallel?

Comment: no, I want to run it one time, but allocate the execution of this single process in 64 threads.

Comment: You would have to implement multi-threading in ./executable from my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to launch a single job, that takes in input two parameters, and split its execution between 128 thread of the CPU with GNUparallel.

This cannot be done. GNU Parallel launches jobs. It does not magically make your single threaded job into a multithreaded job.

In general GNU Parallel is useful if you can express your jobs as:

```
./executable A B
./executable C D
./executable E F
./executable G H
./executable I J
:
./executable Y Z
```

So if you can explain a way to express your jobs this way, GNU Parallel can help you run these in parallel.

Maybe something like this:

```
seq 128 | parallel --dry-run ./executable {} '{= $_++ =}'
```

(Remove `--dry-run` to actually run it).

I think you have gotten a wrong impression of what GNU Parallel is capable of. Consider spending 20 minutes reading chapter 1+2: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014